# tool that will enable me to capture http calls from localhost web server (tomcat) to remote web service (REST calls)

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Can you recommend a tool that will enable me to capture http calls from localhost web server (tomcat) to remote web service (REST calls)?
So when I browse my local site (on same machine where the tomcat) I will be able to see (out of an IDE) all the REST call going from the web server to remote web services?

Comment: Every IDE has a TCP/IP Monitor view.

Comment: You can try Fiddler, in case you are open to catching the requests outside the IDE.

Comment: when using IDE TCP/IP Monitor - what ports do I have to set ? I know the remote webservice I'm calling is listen on port 443 , but how can I enforce the call to go through the monitor ?

Comment: If you're on Windows, Fiddler is your best choice. TCPMon is old but works on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like these one

```
wireshark, traffshow, tcpdump, etc...
```

Comment: These are all TCP level, OP needs HTTP level